# Boot into Xen on debian11 (initrd trouble)

Tags: debian, grub2, initramfs, xen, initrd

```
Linux xd 5.10.0-16-amd64 #1 SMP Debian 5.10.127-1 (2022-06-30) x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

Edit 2022-07-20

This issue has had comes and goes, at the moment, I am having a lot of trouble when Xen boot lands on initramfs, please help.

The wiki suggests to mount a thumb drive or root ( mount -o remount,rw/root ).

Apparently no disks are visible. The complete config files and dmesg and etc can be found at the Xen list, please:

https://lists.xenproject.org/archives/html/xen-users/2022-07/threads.html#00041

https://lists.xenproject.org/archives/html/xen-users/2022-07/msg00057.html

On my debian11, I have installed `xen-hypervisor-4.14-amd64`, `xen-hypervisor-common`, `xen-system-amd64`, and `xen-utils-4.14`

But I cannot boot into Xen, please help.

Theoretically, after installing Xen, according to https://wiki.debian.org/Xen , I should only run:

```
dpkg-divert --divert /etc/grub.d/08_linux_xen --rename /etc/grub.d/20_linux_xen

update-grub
```

Unfortunately, boot breaks and grub mailing list had a very deep debate on it last March-April - apparently multiboot2 will NOT do the trick:

https://www.mail-archive.com/grub-devel@gnu.org/msg32020.html

Apparently all problems lie on `initrd`. DO I need to rebuild `initrd` once I installed Xen? And how do I do it?

**I need some help, please. Is this inconclusive? Is there a work-around I could use (some partial boot on Xen and manually loading on the prompt the rest of what is needed for Xen to work)? How should I proceed? I will try to register this on grub, debian xen packages and Xen as requests/bugs - any further ideas on actions, please?**

The discussion on grub mailing list points to this:

https://wiki.debian.org/DebianInstaller/NetbootFirmware#The_Solution:_Add_Firmware_to_Initramfs

This seems very complicated and risky… is this the way forward?

Did anyone patch grub2 to be able to support what’s needed for Xen, please?

Note: I’m using pure Xen, NOT Eve.

`/etc/default/grub` file contents:

```
# If you change this file, run 'update-grub' afterwards to update
# /boot/grub/grub.cfg.
# For full documentation of the options in this file, see:
#   info -f grub -n 'Simple configuration'

GRUB_DEFAULT=0
GRUB_TIMEOUT=5
GRUB_DISTRIBUTOR=`lsb_release -i -s 2> /dev/null || echo Debian`
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet"
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX=""

# Uncomment to enable BadRAM filtering, modify to suit your needs
# This works with Linux (no patch required) and with any kernel that obtains
# the memory map information from GRUB (GNU Mach, kernel of FreeBSD ...)
#GRUB_BADRAM="0x01234567,0xfefefefe,0x89abcdef,0xefefefef"

# Uncomment to disable graphical terminal (grub-pc only)
#GRUB_TERMINAL=console

# The resolution used on graphical terminal
# note that you can use only modes which your graphic card supports via VBE
# you can see them in real GRUB with the command `vbeinfo'
#GRUB_GFXMODE=640x480

# Uncomment if you don't want GRUB to pass "root=UUID=xxx" parameter to Linux
#GRUB_DISABLE_LINUX_UUID=true

# Uncomment to disable generation of recovery mode menu entries
#GRUB_DISABLE_RECOVERY="true"

# Uncomment to get a beep at grub start
#GRUB_INIT_TUNE="480 440 1"
```

`/boot/grub/grub.cfg` file contents:

```
#
# DO NOT EDIT THIS FILE
#
# It is automatically generated by grub-mkconfig using templates
# from /etc/grub.d and settings from /etc/default/grub
#

### BEGIN /etc/grub.d/00_header ###
if [ -s $prefix/grubenv ]; then
  set have_grubenv=true
  load_env
fi
if [ "${next_entry}" ] ; then
   set default="${next_entry}"
   set next_entry=
   save_env next_entry
   set boot_once=true
else
   set default="Debian GNU/Linux, with Xen hypervisor"
fi

if [ x"${feature_menuentry_id}" = xy ]; then
  menuentry_id_option="--id"
else
  menuentry_id_option=""
fi

export menuentry_id_option

if [ "${prev_saved_entry}" ]; then
  set saved_entry="${prev_saved_entry}"
  save_env saved_entry
  set prev_saved_entry=
  save_env prev_saved_entry
  set boot_once=true
fi

function savedefault {
  if [ -z "${boot_once}" ]; then
    saved_entry="${chosen}"
    save_env saved_entry
  fi
}
function load_video {
  if [ x$feature_all_video_module = xy ]; then
    insmod all_video
  else
    insmod efi_gop
    insmod efi_uga
    insmod ieee1275_fb
    insmod vbe
    insmod vga
    insmod video_bochs
    insmod video_cirrus
  fi
}

if [ x$feature_default_font_path = xy ] ; then
   font=unicode
else
insmod part_gpt
insmod ext2
if [ x$feature_platform_search_hint = xy ]; then
  search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root  0123abcd
else
  search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root 0123abcd
fi
    font="/usr/share/grub/unicode.pf2"
fi

if loadfont $font ; then
  set gfxmode=auto
  load_video
  insmod gfxterm
  set locale_dir=$prefix/locale
  set lang=en_GB
  insmod gettext
fi
terminal_output gfxterm
if [ "${recordfail}" = 1 ] ; then
  set timeout=30
else
  if [ x$feature_timeout_style = xy ] ; then
    set timeout_style=menu
    set timeout=5
  # Fallback normal timeout code in case the timeout_style feature is
  # unavailable.
  else
    set timeout=5
  fi
fi
### END /etc/grub.d/00_header ###

### BEGIN /etc/grub.d/05_debian_theme ###
insmod part_gpt
insmod ext2
if [ x$feature_platform_search_hint = xy ]; then
  search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root  0123abcd
else
  search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root 0123abcd
fi
insmod png
if background_image /usr/share/desktop-base/homeworld-theme/grub/grub-4x3.png; then
  set color_normal=white/black
  set color_highlight=black/white
else
  set menu_color_normal=cyan/blue
  set menu_color_highlight=white/blue
fi
### END /etc/grub.d/05_debian_theme ###

### BEGIN /etc/grub.d/08_linux_xen ###
menuentry 'Debian GNU/Linux, with Xen hypervisor' --class debian --class gnu-linux --class gnu --class os --class xen $menuentry_id_option 'xen-gnulinux-simple-0123abcd' {
    insmod part_gpt
    insmod ext2
    if [ x$feature_platform_search_hint = xy ]; then
      search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root  0123abcd
    else
      search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root 0123abcd
    fi
    echo    'Loading Xen 4.14-amd64 ...'
        if [ "$grub_platform" = "pc" -o "$grub_platform" = "" ]; then
            xen_rm_opts=
        else
            xen_rm_opts="no-real-mode edd=off"
        fi
    multiboot2  /xen-4.14-amd64.gz placeholder   ${xen_rm_opts}
    echo    'Loading Linux 5.10.0-16-amd64 ...'
    module2 /vmlinuz-5.10.0-16-amd64 placeholder root=UUID=0123abcd ro  quiet
    echo    'Loading initial ramdisk ...'
    module2 --nounzip   /initrd.img-5.10.0-16-amd64
}
submenu 'Advanced options for Debian GNU/Linux (with Xen hypervisor)' $menuentry_id_option 'gnulinux-advanced-0123abcd' {
    submenu 'Xen hypervisor, version 4.14-amd64' $menuentry_id_option 'xen-hypervisor-4.14-amd64-0123abcd' {
        menuentry 'Debian GNU/Linux, with Xen 4.14-amd64 and Linux 5.10.0-16-amd64' --class debian --class gnu-linux --class gnu --class os --class xen $menuentry_id_option 'xen-gnulinux-5.10.0-16-amd64-advanced-0123abcd' {
            insmod part_gpt
            insmod ext2
            if [ x$feature_platform_search_hint = xy ]; then
              search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root  0123abcd
            else
              search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root 0123abcd
            fi
            echo    'Loading Xen 4.14-amd64 ...'
                if [ "$grub_platform" = "pc" -o "$grub_platform" = "" ]; then
                    xen_rm_opts=
                else
                    xen_rm_opts="no-real-mode edd=off"
                fi
            multiboot2  /xen-4.14-amd64.gz placeholder   ${xen_rm_opts}
            echo    'Loading Linux 5.10.0-16-amd64 ...'
            module2 /vmlinuz-5.10.0-16-amd64 placeholder root=UUID=0123abcd ro  quiet
            echo    'Loading initial ramdisk ...'
            module2 --nounzip   /initrd.img-5.10.0-16-amd64
        }
        menuentry 'Debian GNU/Linux, with Xen 4.14-amd64 and Linux 5.10.0-16-amd64 (recovery mode)' --class debian --class gnu-linux --class gnu --class os --class xen $menuentry_id_option 'xen-gnulinux-5.10.0-16-amd64-recovery-0123abcd' {
            insmod part_gpt
            insmod ext2
            if [ x$feature_platform_search_hint = xy ]; then
              search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root  0123abcd
            else
              search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root 0123abcd
            fi
            echo    'Loading Xen 4.14-amd64 ...'
                if [ "$grub_platform" = "pc" -o "$grub_platform" = "" ]; then
                    xen_rm_opts=
                else
                    xen_rm_opts="no-real-mode edd=off"
                fi
            multiboot2  /xen-4.14-amd64.gz placeholder  ${xen_rm_opts}
            echo    'Loading Linux 5.10.0-16-amd64 ...'
            module2 /vmlinuz-5.10.0-16-amd64 placeholder root=UUID=0123abcd ro single 
            echo    'Loading initial ramdisk ...'
            module2 --nounzip   /initrd.img-5.10.0-16-amd64
        }
    }
    submenu 'Xen hypervisor, version 4.14-amd64.efi' $menuentry_id_option 'xen-hypervisor-4.14-amd64.efi-0123abcd' {
        menuentry 'Debian GNU/Linux, with Xen 4.14-amd64.efi and Linux 5.10.0-16-amd64' --class debian --class gnu-linux --class gnu --class os --class xen $menuentry_id_option 'xen-gnulinux-5.10.0-16-amd64-advanced-0123abcd' {
            insmod part_gpt
            insmod ext2
            if [ x$feature_platform_search_hint = xy ]; then
              search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root  0123abcd
            else
              search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root 0123abcd
            fi
            echo    'Loading Xen 4.14-amd64.efi ...'
                if [ "$grub_platform" = "pc" -o "$grub_platform" = "" ]; then
                    xen_rm_opts=
                else
                    xen_rm_opts="no-real-mode edd=off"
                fi
            multiboot2  /xen-4.14-amd64.efi placeholder   ${xen_rm_opts}
            echo    'Loading Linux 5.10.0-16-amd64 ...'
            module2 /vmlinuz-5.10.0-16-amd64 placeholder root=UUID=0123abcd ro  quiet
            echo    'Loading initial ramdisk ...'
            module2 --nounzip   /initrd.img-5.10.0-16-amd64
        }
        menuentry 'Debian GNU/Linux, with Xen 4.14-amd64.efi and Linux 5.10.0-16-amd64 (recovery mode)' --class debian --class gnu-linux --class gnu --class os --class xen $menuentry_id_option 'xen-gnulinux-5.10.0-16-amd64-recovery-0123abcd' {
            insmod part_gpt
            insmod ext2
            if [ x$feature_platform_search_hint = xy ]; then
              search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root  0123abcd
            else
              search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root 0123abcd
            fi
            echo    'Loading Xen 4.14-amd64.efi ...'
                if [ "$grub_platform" = "pc" -o "$grub_platform" = "" ]; then
                    xen_rm_opts=
                else
                    xen_rm_opts="no-real-mode edd=off"
                fi
            multiboot2  /xen-4.14-amd64.efi placeholder  ${xen_rm_opts}
            echo    'Loading Linux 5.10.0-16-amd64 ...'
            module2 /vmlinuz-5.10.0-16-amd64 placeholder root=UUID=0123abcd ro single 
            echo    'Loading initial ramdisk ...'
            module2 --nounzip   /initrd.img-5.10.0-16-amd64
        }
    }
}

### END /etc/grub.d/08_linux_xen ###

### BEGIN /etc/grub.d/10_linux ###
function gfxmode {
    set gfxpayload="${1}"
}
set linux_gfx_mode=
export linux_gfx_mode
menuentry 'Debian GNU/Linux' --class debian --class gnu-linux --class gnu --class os $menuentry_id_option 'gnulinux-simple-0123abcd' {
    load_video
    insmod gzio
    if [ x$grub_platform = xxen ]; then insmod xzio; insmod lzopio; fi
    insmod part_gpt
    insmod ext2
    if [ x$feature_platform_search_hint = xy ]; then
      search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root  0123abcd
    else
      search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root 0123abcd
    fi
    echo    'Loading Linux 5.10.0-16-amd64 ...'
    linux   /vmlinuz-5.10.0-16-amd64 root=UUID=0123abcd ro  quiet
    echo    'Loading initial ramdisk ...'
    initrd  /initrd.img-5.10.0-16-amd64
}
submenu 'Advanced options for Debian GNU/Linux' $menuentry_id_option 'gnulinux-advanced-0123abcd' {
    menuentry 'Debian GNU/Linux, with Linux 5.10.0-16-amd64' --class debian --class gnu-linux --class gnu --class os $menuentry_id_option 'gnulinux-5.10.0-16-amd64-advanced-0123abcd' {
        load_video
        insmod gzio
        if [ x$grub_platform = xxen ]; then insmod xzio; insmod lzopio; fi
        insmod part_gpt
        insmod ext2
        if [ x$feature_platform_search_hint = xy ]; then
          search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root  0123abcd
        else
          search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root 0123abcd
        fi
        echo    'Loading Linux 5.10.0-16-amd64 ...'
        linux   /vmlinuz-5.10.0-16-amd64 root=UUID=0123abcd ro  quiet
        echo    'Loading initial ramdisk ...'
        initrd  /initrd.img-5.10.0-16-amd64
    }
    menuentry 'Debian GNU/Linux, with Linux 5.10.0-16-amd64 (recovery mode)' --class debian --class gnu-linux --class gnu --class os $menuentry_id_option 'gnulinux-5.10.0-16-amd64-recovery-0123abcd' {
        load_video
        insmod gzio
        if [ x$grub_platform = xxen ]; then insmod xzio; insmod lzopio; fi
        insmod part_gpt
        insmod ext2
        if [ x$feature_platform_search_hint = xy ]; then
          search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root  0123abcd
        else
          search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root 0123abcd
        fi
        echo    'Loading Linux 5.10.0-16-amd64 ...'
        linux   /vmlinuz-5.10.0-16-amd64 root=UUID=0123abcd ro single 
        echo    'Loading initial ramdisk ...'
        initrd  /initrd.img-5.10.0-16-amd64
    }
}

### END /etc/grub.d/10_linux ###

### BEGIN /etc/grub.d/30_os-prober ###
### END /etc/grub.d/30_os-prober ###

### BEGIN /etc/grub.d/30_uefi-firmware ###
menuentry 'System setup' $menuentry_id_option 'uefi-firmware' {
    fwsetup
}
### END /etc/grub.d/30_uefi-firmware ###

### BEGIN /etc/grub.d/40_custom ###
# This file provides an easy way to add custom menu entries.  Simply type the
# menu entries you want to add after this comment.  Be careful not to change
# the 'exec tail' line above.
### END /etc/grub.d/40_custom ###

### BEGIN /etc/grub.d/41_custom ###
if [ -f  ${config_directory}/custom.cfg ]; then
  source ${config_directory}/custom.cfg
elif [ -z "${config_directory}" -a -f  $prefix/custom.cfg ]; then
  source $prefix/custom.cfg;
fi
### END /etc/grub.d/41_custom ###
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately Xen is not compatible with this hardware.

For traceability, this was discussed on the xen-devel here:

https://xen.markmail.org/message/7jgv47pk5rsea4ef?q=+list:com%2Exensource%2Elists%2Exen-devel&page=6

This firmware has a wider than 16bit segment number and nvme calls to it during boot, and this is the root problem.

Xen is not compatible with this kind of hardware yet.

As it was reported on xen-devel, it is always possible that a good soul implements this new functionality (maybe a new hypercall sun-function). Or all hardware evolve enough for them to implement.

I will follow people’s advice and migrate to KVM with Quemu as unfortunately Xen is not compatible with that hardware.

I have also asked a 16 but PCI firmware update to Acer:

https://community.acer.com/en/discussion/669340/acer-aspire-5-a517-52g-firmware-w-16-bit-pci-segment-size/p1?new=1